# Problems with double Sum

Tags: summation

I have some decent problems with performing a double summation. 
The Sum is as follows

```
Sum[
 f[M[2, 1],M[2, 2]]
 , {M[2, 1], -Border, Border}
 , {M[2, 2], -Border, Border}
]
```

over some function `f`, and this summation gives me the right result.
However I want to generalize this thing in the following way

```
Sum[
 Sum[
  f[M[2, 1],M[2, 2]]
  , {M[2, i], -Border, Border}]
 , {i, 1, 2}
]
```

which doesn't give me the right result and I cannot understand why.
Can anybody tell me what is going wrong here and more importantly, how to make this generalized sum work?!

greets
mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is

```
Sum[f[M[2, 1], M[2, 2]], 
  Evaluate[Sequence @@ Table[{M[2, i], -Border, Border}, {i, 1, 2}]]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked out for me!

Comment: You're welcome. The usual way of giving thanks on StackExchange is to up-vote an answer and to check the tick mark to accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
Fold[Sum[#, {m[2, #2], -b, b}] &,  f[m[2, 1], m[2, 2]], {2, 1}]

TexForm @ %
```

> $\sum _{m(2,1)=-b}^b \left(\sum _{m(2,2)=-b}^b f(m(2,1),m(2,2))\right)$